# Apply "draw" method code to views from style

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-viewgroup

I want to set a watermark to certain views (mostly viewgroups) of my app.

I managed to create the watermark with some canvas redrawing within the `onDraw()` method, but to apply my demo I needed to create a sublass of `FragmentLayout` in order to replace the FragmentLayout in the layout with the `WatermarkFragmentLayout`.

In the project, the views that need to be applied range from ConstraintLayout, FrameLayout, LinearLayout, CardViews, RecyclerViews, etc. Additionally there are probably 100+ screens where the watermark needs to be applied in these views.

I wouldn't want to create a subclass for each viewgroup, and then change all the layouts to use that class.

Is there a better way to do so?

Just to add, the watermark is meant to be "bellow" the widgets, in a similar fashion to a background but with some logic applied to it so that watermark text varies:

[image: watermark example]

Comment: Subclass `Drawable` and put your `Canvas` code in its `draw()` override, then add that `Drawable` to each `View[Group]`'s overlay: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewOverlay.

Comment: Also, I just realized, if your `minSdk` is at least 24 (I think), you might be able to specify your custom `Drawable` class in a `drawable` resource, which would allow you to set it via the `android:foreground` attribute without the additional overlay code, and you'd also be able to use it in a `style`. I've not tested that yet, though.

Comment: ^That does work, btw, and it is from API level 24, as I'd remembered. Beginning with that version, you can do something like `<drawable class="com.your.package.CustomDrawable" />` in a resource drawable XML file, and use that for `android:foreground` on a `<View>` or in a `style`. For this setup, the `CustomDrawable` class must have a public empty constructor, so any parameters you might've needed would have to be handled through XML attributes. Those attributes are accessed in code in `Drawable`'s `inflate()` overrides, where you'd handle them similarly to how it's done for a custom `View`.

Comment: Thank you @MikeM., the issue with the overlay is that it is OVER the view, which well that is normal for a watermark but actually I need it to be bellow the other components (kind of a background with a watermark)

Comment: I just read the following comments, that seem like a good idea, current version is 23 but maybe I can convince to upgrade it.

Comment: You could use `CustomDrawable` as the background instead, then, yeah? Still better than subclassing each one, at least. At 24, you would use it in a `style`'s `android:background`.

Comment: @MikeM.so just to apply it, how could I get the height of the view or estimated height and width when I apply the draw method of CustomDrawable so that I can perform my canvas drawing

Comment: A background drawable fills the `View`, so its bounds will be the same size as the `View`. You can just use `getBounds()` or `bounds`, depending on your language, and then use its `width()` and `height()`.